# Updata value of a chart with data in computed part

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have to make charts in vue js. But the data I get are in a vuex store. I can get access to them with the computed, but I didn't manage to update the chart with.

Here's the code:

```
<template>
<v-content>
    <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex v-for="(chart, id) in charts" :key="id" v-bind="{['xs'+chart.size]: true}">
                <RedmineChart :name="chart.name" :type="chart.type" :getData="chart.getData"
                              :refresh="chart.refresh" :chartOptions="chart.chartOptions" :info="chart.info"
                              :context="chart.context"/>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</v-content>
```

```
<script>
    import {mapGetters, mapState} from 'vuex'
    export default {
        name: 'globalView',
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters('tickets', {
                archiTickets: 'ticketsFromArchi',
            }),
        },
        data() {
            return {
                temps: [
                    {
                        name: 'Assigned / Late (Archi)',
                        info: '<b>Assigned:</b> Number of <b>open</b> redmine assigned to Groupe Archi SOA</br><b>Late:</b> Number of redmine assigned to Groupe Archi SOA not delivered at due date',
                        type: 'Number',
                        refresh: 5,
                        size: 6,
                        getData() {
                            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                let res = []
                                res.push({label: 'Assigned', number: archiTickets.length})
                            })
                        }
                    }
                ],
    }
</script>
```

When I debug, it says that archoTickets is undefined even with this.archiTickets.

Is there a way to get rid of this problem or should I change the struct of the application?

Thank you

Comment: `number: archiTickets.length` should be `number: this.archiTickets.length`

Comment: You may have to do a little fiddling to get the right `this`.

Comment: try this:
`data() {
var _this = this;
    return {`...`_this.archiTickets.length`...

Comment: It works, not sure it is well designed but it works thank you